# Как определить число div-ов одного класса

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте! На странице множество div-ов одного и тогоже класса, не подскажете, как определить их число на javascript?

Comment: может тебе сразу нужно сделать поиск по классу?Что-то мне подсказывает что оно тебе потребуется http://javascript.ru/unsorted/top-10-functions#8-getelementsbyclass

Answer (score 3):

```
function fn( el, className ) {
  var elements = document.getElementsByTagName(el);
  var total = 0;
  for( var i=-1; ++i < elements.length; ) {
    if( ~elements[i].className.search(className) ) {
      ++total;
    }
  }
  return total;
}

fn('div', 'someClassName')

// if (window.jQuery !== undefined) {
    $('div.someClassName').length
//}
```

Answer (score 1):

для jquery это будет просто:

```
alert( $('div.myClass').length );
```

Comment: выберит не только дивы

Comment: ну да, поправил ;) суть не меняется ;)

Comment: меняется в корне, т.к. если селектор будет просто `.selector`. то Sizzle выполнет обычный `getElementsByClassName`, а если нет, то будет выполнен `querySelectorAll`, который более медленный

Answer (score 1):

Функция пересечения массивов взята [отсюда](http://dunaevv1.narod.ru/sets_brel.htm)

```
function across(a1, a2){ // a1, a2 - массивы одномерные
    var arez=new Array();
    if (a1.length==0 || a2.length==0) return arez var i=0,j; while (i<a1.length){   // для каждого элемента a1
      j=0
      while (j<a2.length){
        if (a1[i]==a2[j]) {
           arez.push(a1[i]);
           break;
        }
        j++;
      } i++;
  }
 return arez }
```

Теперь осталось найти пересечение массивов:

```
arr1= document.getElementsByTagName("div");
arr2= document.getElementsByClassName("class");
```

Функция `document.getElementsByClassName` не кроссбраузерна. Здесь [кросс](http://javascript.ru/unsorted/top-10-functions#8-getelementsbyclass).

Еще можно получить все div и считать те у которых className равно нужному классу.

Comment: Какой-то глюк у местного парсера.

Comment: Парсер в норме :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log(document.querySelectorAll("div.x").length)
```

```html
<div class=x><div><div><div class=y><div></div><div class=x></div></div></div></div></div><div class=x><div><div><div class=y><div></div><div class=x></div></div></div></div></div><div class=x><div><div><div class=y><div></div><div class=x></div></div></div></div></div><div class=x><div><div><div class=y><div></div><div class=x></div></div></div></div></div><div class=x><div><div><div class=y><div></div><div class=x></div></div></div></div></div><div class=x><div><div><div class=y><div></div><div class=x></div></div></div></div></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

А не быстрее ли будет искать сначала по классу, а потом по тегу?

```
els = document.getElementsByClassName('clear');
length = els.length;
count = 0;
for (;length--;) {
    count += els[length].tagName == 'DIV' ? 1 : 0;
}
return count;
```

Comment: Во первых - getElementsByClassName не кроссбраузерно, в отличии от getElementsByTagName, во вторых:

> var? не, не слышал

Comment: > getElementsByClassName не кроссбраузерно
это печально.
> var? не, не слышал
лень писать всю функцию.

Comment: @technobulka а комментарий не лень?..

Comment: по-моему вы изобрели `reduce`

    Array.prototype.reduce.call(
        document.getElementsByClassName('clear'), 
        function(acc,el){
            return acc+(el.tagName == 'DIV' ? 1 : 0);
        },
        0
    );

Comment: как видишь.